# Tool to create ContentType CAML

Tags: visual-studio, content-type

Are there any good tools to create the CAML required for ContentTypes? I'm building most of my content types in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should definitively check out [SharePoint Manager 2010](http://spm.codeplex.com/). Use the standard SharePoint 2010 user interface to create fields and content types, and use SPM to extract the CAML afterwards. For more information, check out [this excellent blog post](http://kjellsj.blogspot.com/2009/07/sharepoint-list-content-type-forms.html) by the magician [KjellSJ](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/4479/kjellsj). It's for SP2007, but it still applies.

Comment: Thanks, I already do use SharePoint manager. But I'm more looking for a tool that can create the CAML code without creating the ContentType!

Answer (score 3):

One tool which it might be worth looking at is [Visual Studio 11](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us).

I'd not recommend that you use it for production yet. But you can still use the Content Type and List designers and then copy the generated files into your VS2010 project